# Getting wagtail to use correct mime types for Documents

Tags: wagtail

We have a wagtail (2.0.1) install with documents enabled, but uploading a pdf leads to links to that pdf that don't use the correct mime-type for previewing in the browser. Instead they just instantly go to file download.

Looking at the header, the reply contains:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

which for documents is almost always the wrong mime-type, especially documents that have built-in browser "previews". Is there a way to configure which mime-types to use for which document extensions (settings.py, a mime-type-for-extension admin interface that requires a plugin, etc.)?

Comment: Note that this is an open issue (https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1416), and specifically affects remote storage backends (e.g. `S3BotoStorage`) which do not expose a local filepath.

Comment: Not sure I understand that problem: the database has the full document filename, so wagtail should be able to just use whatever "extension -> mime-type" dict a user specifies when the document is requested through wagtail? The document is served "through" wagtail, updating the content-type header should be fairly straight forward (none of the other things noted in that issue seem necessary to fix document types, they're a way more elaborate storage solution overhaul it looks like?)

Comment: Looking at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1/advanced_topics/documents/custom_document_model.html, is there a way to change how the documents are served so that the mime type is guessed at request-time from the document's filename? Having that sometimes be wrong is infinitely preferable to having the mimetype _always_ be wrong =) (is there an example that shows how to make a custom Document class that overrides the serving function?)

Comment: The serve logic happens in a view function https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/documents/views/serve.py rather than a model method, so a custom document model wouldn't help - you'd have to replace (or wrap) the view to customise it. Looking deeper into the code, this would actually be a very simple thing to fix within Wagtail - I was previously under the impression that `mimetypes.guess_type` worked off the file content (which isn't available at serve time for remote storages), but in fact it just uses the filename.

Comment: Oh that sounds quite positive - is there a new issue for just putting in the mimetypes.guess_type check by any chance?